# How to create properly tree-hierarchy

Tags: database-design

I'm using web2py to create an application

I've got 2 different roles: client and referents. Every client can have multiple referents. 
Both client and referent can insert row in a table, called object.

The user table, where client and referent are registered, has a column called "client_id".
Every referent in the column_id has the id of the client to whom he reference to.

The problem is: which value should a client have in client_id?
A possible answer could be NULL or the id of the client itself.

Which one is better? Or there's something better?

Comment: Can you add some more detail to make your question easier to understand?  The actual table definitions along with sample data would help.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason why I'd choose `NULL` is a bit simpler queries - you don't need to care about self-relationship when you are querying ,for instance, number of referred users by the given. You can also save some space in case you create an index on `client_id` (it usually makes sense) because some RDMS, for example Oracle, don't include `NULL`s into index, others, like SQL server, allow filtered indexes (`WHERE client_id IS NOT NULL`).

Comment: The statement "*Oracle does not include NULL in an index*" is not entirely true. When indexing more than one column, the combination `(1,NULL)` *will* be put into the index. But in this case when you only index one column, you are of course right. (And I agree: `NULL` is the most reasonable choice to store into `client_id` for that situation)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : You are absolutely right, I was talking about indexing single column.